# How to use this project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android development. Actually today is my second day. I downloaded this code for an app and I want to test it if it works or not. I downloaded it from **[here](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123).**
I am using android studio but I have no idea where to import this code so I can test it. I tried to search google but I am not sure if I am looking for package import or java or android application library. This all is very confusing to me. Can someone tell me how can I import and run this code in android studio IDE.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the Android Development Bundle.  It is Eclipse with an SDK build by Android for Android.  It will make things much easier on you.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

After that, you can simply go to File->Import.

Comment: I understand, but my question is specifically for android studio!

Comment: K, best of luck to you then!  Sorry I cannot help.

Comment: you did give me a very good hint though and then I was able to figure it out from there. SO I will give you point.

Answer (score 1):

try this out [Migrating from eclipse to studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)